# Difficulty setting up a solid of revolution integral

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

I am trying to find the volume of the region between the parabola $y^2=8x$ and the line $x=2$ revolved around the $y$ axis.

My intuition is that taking an infinitesimal horizontal slice of the parabola, the width should be 
$$
2-\frac{y^2}{8}
$$
Which we would square and multiply by $\pi$ and the infinitesimal height $\mathrm dy$, yielding the integral:
$$
\pi\int_{-4}^4(2-\frac{y^2}{8})^2\mathrm dy
$$
With the bounds coming from the intersection of $y^2=8x$ and $x=2$. However, any way I slice it, this isn't giving me the answer in the book, which is 
$$
\frac{128\pi}{5}
$$
Where am I going wrong? The next part asks me to revolve around $x=2$, so any tips there would be helpful too! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cross-section  is obtained by removing a  disk of radius $y^2/8$ from a disk of radius $2$. That gives volume
$$\int_{-4}^4 \pi \cdot(2^2)\,dy-\int_{-4}^4 \pi \cdot\frac{y^4}{64}\,dy.$$
The first integral gives the volume of a cylinder, and we need not use integration to compute that! And I would prefer to integrate from $0$ to $4$ and double.

Alternately, one could use the Method of Cylindrical Shells. That is somewhat less pleasant in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a better way to do it. Just wondering, do you see anything obviously wrong with what I had done? It seemed sound

Comment: @qbert:  If you were rotating about the line $x=2$, the radius in your post would be correct. But in our case the cross-section at height $y$ has a hole in it, so we need to worry about outer radius and inner radius.  Sometimes in American calculus books the cross-section is called a "washer."  We need to integrate the area of that washer from $-4$ to $4$. That gives alternate formulation $\int_{-4}^4 \pi\left(2^2-(y^2/8)^2\right)\,dy$.  Same result.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @qbert: You are welcome.

Comment: soon I will get to the point where a few users like yourself on here have taught me more than my professors!

Comment: @qbert: Ultimately you teach yourself. Books and instructors are just assistants in this.